# Execute command on multiple files

Tags: bash, scripting, shell-scripting

I need to execute [jpeg-recompress](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/jpeg-archive) on thousands of files. I've tried:

```
for image in *.jpg; do
    image2=${image%.*}.jpg;
    ./jpeg-recompress /path/to/images/$image /path/to/images/$image2;
    echo "Processing $image2 file...";
done
```

But fails to do so arguing that the: `Maximum number of arguments exceeded`
I tried using find, something like:

```
find /path/to/images -iname “*.jpg” | while read image; do
```

(and the rest of the previous argument)

But it doesn't seem to do anything. I was wondering how could I take advantage of this program on multiple files?

```
jpeg-recompress image.jpg image.jpg
```

(Does replace the original, as intended)

Comment: The double-quotes in your `find` command look like fancy unicode quotes, which do not  function as shell quotes (they'll get treated as part of the filename pattern to search for, not quotes *around* the pattern). Try it again with plain ASCII quotes.

Answer (score 0):

**Large file lists**

There are many ways to get around this.  The first that comes to mind is using find.

```
for image in `find /path/to/jpegs -type f -name *.jpg`
do
 something
done
```

There is also an `xargs` command that may prove useful.

Continuing to use a for loop can be advantageous; vs using find alone, as you can append a log file with the jpeg files you have processed, so you can skip them next time you run the command, should you desire to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple with just a find:

```
find /path/to/images -name '*.jpg' -exec jpeg-recompress {} \;
```

Or if you have multiple cores you could get more fancy and write a loop that compressed multiple files in parallel